# Is there a simple way to convert a list of integers to a formatted string in Python?

Tags: python, list, tostring

I am writing a program which generates a list of integers, for example:

```
[2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 15, 18, 19, 20]
```

This list can be very long, but it contains many consecutive values, as seen in this example.

In order to store it (in a database), I would like to convert it to a formatted string, in the following format:

```
"2,5-10,15,18-20"
```

I already have in mind a solution, which is iterating through the whole list to detect consecutive values and building the string.

My question is: is there another, simpler way of doing this conversion in Python?

Comment: The short answer is... No.

Comment: take a look at http://pyseq.rsgalloway.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly simple, but this produces the desired results:

```
from itertools import groupby, count
from operator import itemgetter

a = [2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 15, 18, 19, 20]
formatted = ','.join(str(x) if x == y else "{}-{}".format(x, y) for x, y in [itemgetter(0, -1)(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(a, lambda n, c = count(): n - next(c))])

print(formatted)
```

Which displays:

```
2,5-10,15,18-20
```

Comment: Indeed, it is not simple, but it works exactly as intended, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, the solution you propose is the only option:

- Iterate over items, storing the first number in the sequence
- If the next number is not the next in the sequence, build "first-last" string and add to list of sequences.

No reason to store as string, can be stored as a list of strings instead